# Check if value of one key in json has another key

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

I'm trying to print my json content. I know how to print just keys and values but I want to have access to the objects within the keys too. This is my code:

```
json_mini = json.loads('{"one" : {"testing" : 39, "this": 17}, "two" : "2", "three" : "3"}')
for index, value in json_mini.items():
    print index, value
    if value.items():
        for ind2, val2 in value.items():
            print ind2, val2
```

which gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'`

How to iterate over it? So I can do some process on each separate key and value?

Comment: You could check `if isinstance(value, dict)`. What did you want `value.items()` to return when `value` is `"2"` ?

Comment: You need a recursive function because your JSON is multilevel

Comment: @AleksandrBorisov can you provide the solution for Python 2.7?

Comment: What is wrong with the question so I got down vote?

Comment: @khelwood your solution works!

Comment: Thanks for that sweet down votes and thanks for help @khelwood

Comment: too many downvotes, yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive example:

```
import json


def func(data):
    for index, value in data.items():
        print index, value
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            func(value)


json_mini = json.loads('{"one" : {"testing" : 39, "this": 17}, "two" : "2", "three" : "3"}')
func(json_mini)
```

Comment: Thank you, I hope your answer will help someone else too because in stack overflow there is only solution for Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive way that works in Python 2 and 3, which doesn't use `isinstance()`. It instead uses exceptions to determine whether a given element is a sub-object or not.

```
import json

def func(obj, name=''):
    try:
        for key, value in obj.items():
            func(value, key)
    except AttributeError:
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, obj))

json_mini = json.loads('''{
                              "three": "3",
                              "two": "2",
                              "one": {
                                  "this": 17,
                                  "testing": 39
                              }
                          }''')

func(json_mini)
```

Output:

```
this: 17
testing: 39
three: 3
two: 2
```